# JavaFX controller for a poker game

Tags: java, playing-cards, controller, javafx

I am making a poker application in JavaFX. When I try to display the cards on the screen it is working perfectly fine. Yet I have a method with a lot of duplicated code in it.

I have tried to compress the code into 1 function with a for loop but I couldn't get it to work. Anyone has an idea how to get rid of the duplication?

```
public class GameController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private Canvas canvasBoard;
    @FXML
    private Canvas canvasPlayer1;
    @FXML
    private Canvas canvasPlayer2;
    @FXML
    private Canvas canvasPlayer3;
    @FXML
    private Canvas canvasPlayer4;

    private int playerCardsWidth1 = 0;
    private int playerCardsWidth2 = 0;
    private int playerCardsWidth3 = 0;
    private int playerCardsWidth4 = 0;
    private int dealerCardsWidth = 0;
    private TexasHoldem game;
    private IPlayer board;

    public GameController() {
        try {
            game = new TexasHoldem();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void showCardsBoard() {

        board = game.getBoard();

        dealerCardsWidth += 50;
        for (ICard c : board.getCards()) {
            String foto = c.getFilename();
            Image image = new Image(foto);
            GraphicsContext gcBoard = canvasBoard.getGraphicsContext2D();
            int dealerCardsHeight = 0;
            gcBoard.drawImage(image,dealerCardsWidth, dealerCardsHeight,60,80);
            dealerCardsWidth += 75;
        }
    }

    private void showCardsPlayers() {

        List<IPlayer> spelers = game.getPlayers();

        for (int i = 0; i < spelers.size(); i++) {

            if (i == 0) {
                IPlayer player1 = spelers.get(i);
                for (ICard c : player1.getCards()) {
                    Image image = new Image(c.getFilename());
                    GraphicsContext gc1 = canvasPlayer1.getGraphicsContext2D();
                    int playerCardsHeight1 = 0;
                    gc1.drawImage(image, playerCardsWidth1, playerCardsHeight1, 60, 80);
                    playerCardsWidth1 += 75;
                }

            }
            if (i == 1) {
                IPlayer player2 = spelers.get(i);
                for (ICard c : player2.getCards()) {
                    Image image = new Image(c.getFilename());
                    GraphicsContext gc2 = canvasPlayer2.getGraphicsContext2D();
                    int playerCardsHeight2 = 0;
                    gc2.drawImage(image, playerCardsWidth2, playerCardsHeight2, 60, 80);
                    playerCardsWidth2 += 75;
                }
            }
            if (i == 2) {

                IPlayer player3 = spelers.get(i);
                for (ICard c : player3.getCards()) {
                    Image image = new Image(c.getFilename());
                    GraphicsContext gc3 = canvasPlayer3.getGraphicsContext2D();
                    int playerCardsHeight3 = 0;
                    gc3.drawImage(image, playerCardsWidth3, playerCardsHeight3, 60, 80);
                    playerCardsWidth3 += 75;
                }
            }
            if (i == 3) {

                IPlayer player4 = spelers.get(i);
                for (ICard c : player4.getCards()) {
                    Image image = new Image(c.getFilename());
                    GraphicsContext gc4 = canvasPlayer4.getGraphicsContext2D();
                    int playerCardsHeight4 = 0;
                    gc4.drawImage(image, playerCardsWidth4, playerCardsHeight4, 60, 80);
                    playerCardsWidth4 += 75;
                }
            }
        }      
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Logic**:

If statements differs only in 2 variables: **canvasPlayerX** and **playerCardsWidthX**.

**playerCardsWidthX**: looks like this var can be converted to local, just like playerCardsHeightX;

**canvasPlayerX**: you can do one little trick here - add player canvases to a list in initialize() method, and then refer to the i-th player canvas as `playersCanvases.get(i)`;

Moreover, your code didnt even compile, because GameController should implement initialize(..) method;

**Codestyle**:

- **playerCardsWidthX** - in your code, its not width of player cards, its coordinate, where to draw next card. Consider renaming;
- in constructor, exception is caught, and stacktrace is printed, but after that, program will continue its flow. Is this what you want? (see code below for possible solution).
- extract constants into private static final fields

---

```
public class GameController implements Initializable {
public static final int CARD_WIDTH = 60;
public static final int CARD_HEIGHT = 80;
public static final int CARD_SPACING = 15;

public static final int CARDS_X_DIFF = CARD_WIDTH + CARD_SPACING;

@FXML
private Canvas canvasBoard;
@FXML
private Canvas canvasPlayer1;
@FXML
private Canvas canvasPlayer2;
@FXML
private Canvas canvasPlayer3;
@FXML
private Canvas canvasPlayer4;

private List<Canvas> playersCanvases;

private TexasHoldem game;
private IPlayer board;

public GameController() {
    try {
        game = new TexasHoldem();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Platform.exit();
    }
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    // in initialize method, because in constructor canvases are not assigned(== null)
    playersCanvases = Arrays.asList(canvasPlayer1, canvasPlayer2, canvasPlayer3, canvasPlayer4);
}

private void showBoardCards() {
    board = game.getBoard();
    showCards(50, board.getCards(), canvasBoard.getGraphicsContext2D());
}

private void showPlayersCards() {
    List<IPlayer> players = game.getPlayers();
    for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++) {
        IPlayer player = players.get(i);
        showCards(0, player.getCards(), playersCanvases.get(i).getGraphicsContext2D());
    }
}

private void showCards(int xOffset, List<ICard> cards, GraphicsContext gc) {
    int cardY = 0;
    int cardX = xOffset;
    for (ICard c : cards) {
        Image image = new Image(c.getFilename());
        gc.drawImage(image, cardX, cardY, CARD_WIDTH, CARD_HEIGHT);
        cardX += CARDS_X_DIFF;
    }
}
```

}